# My HTTP POST in javascript isn't running my function in my google apps script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have been trying for a couple hours now to see if I can send POST DATA to a google apps script web app. I'm attempting to make my data that's sent send me an email. But when i run my code no errors appear. Just nothing happens.

Here is my html, it's just a button to run the function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--Import JQUERY-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="submitClicked()">submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my javascript meant to send the request

```
function submitClicked() {
    sendData();
}

function sendData() {
    console.log("running");

    const url = "https://script.google.com/a/macros/limitlessflight.com/s/AKfycbyAhx3wCRR4fS30ZrVpFpe-lxksRjn8ZWTUmTj5YlbmD8wG2PlzzXzDNUUaS8ntu09LBQ/exec";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
        value: "hello"
    }));
    
    console.log("done");
}
```

And here is my apps script code to send an email. When i run this code by itself, or entering the page it works correctly. I added the doGet(e) function, just so I could test if a GET request would work instead.

```
function doPost(e) {
  emailForm(e);
}

function doGet(e) {
  emailForm(e);
}

function emailForm(data) {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: "youremailhere@emailhere.com",
        subject: "Test Email",
        htmlBody: data
      });
}
```

Comment: I think you need to set up a service account for your website

Comment: Provide publishing details as written in [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Try adding `xhr.error` and `xhr.load` handlers to see what response is returned?

Comment: In order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide the detailed setting of your Web Apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Google Apps Script web application is incomplete as the doPost and doGet functions don't return one of the required objects. From [Requirements for web apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#requirements_for_web_apps)

> - The function returns an HTML service HtmlOutput object or a Content service TextOutput object.

A simple fix is to add `return ContentService.createTextOutput('Success!');` to the end of each of these functions:

```
function doPost(e) {
  emailForm(e);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('Success!');
}


function doGet(e) {
  emailForm(e);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('Success!');  
}
```